# Dynamic dimension array multiplication

Tags: r

I am in a situation, where I need to multiply the arrays with no known array number and array dimension. For example:

```
demo1 = c(0.45, 0.55)
demo2 = c(0.1, 0.1, 0.15, 0.15, 0.2, 0.05, 0.15, 0.1)

myarr <- array(1:n, dim = c(length(demo1), length(demo2)))

for (p in 1:length(demo1)){
    for (q in 1:length(demo2)){
        myarr[p,q] <- demo1[p]*demo2[q]
    }
}
```

It is OK, when we know number of demos. But I have no idea when I don't know the number of demo and still need to make an array of the dimension of the multiplication of their length. So, I may have number of demo = 3 or 4 or 5 and so on. How to generalize the statement inside for loop above. As I am very new to R, I will appreciate your quick help on this. Many thanks in advance

Comment: thanks David for rectifying typo..

Comment: I don't really understand when you know ``demo1`` or ``demo2``. But as long as ``demo1`` and ``demo2`` do not grow really large, you could repeat the calculation for the current ``demo1`` and ``demo2``. You may want to have a look at: ``demo1 %o% demo2`` which makes use of R's vectorisation and is much faster (and shorter) than the ``for``-loops.

Comment: Thanks Phann for the reply. No of demos can be more than 2. There can be demo3, demo4 and so on..

Comment: And how should the result look like then? demo1 * demo2 * demo3 * ...? Or an n-dimensional array?

Comment: myarr <- demo1 %o% demo2 %o% demo3 .....

Comment: So, does that answer your question? If you get a new ``demoX`` you could just do ``myarr %o% demoX`` and add this new demo to your array. For further answers more information is needed, e.g. where are the new demo is coming from (from a folder with a new file or somewhere else?). How is it assigned or read? If my comment is sufficient, I would post it as answer to complete the question.

Comment: Thanks So much Phann... I got what was required. :)

Comment: Would be great if you accept the answer then.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at `?outer` or the shortform `%o%` to multiply your vectors:

```
myarr <- demo1 %o% demo2 %o% demo3 # %o%...
```

Of course, you could do that iteratively in the case that new vectors should be added:

```
myarr <- demo1 %o% demo2
myarr <- myarr %o% demo3 
#...
```

As additional information: `For`-loops are very slow in R and shouldnt be used if *vectorization* could be used.

Using vectorization instead of loops gives a time advantage of about 1000:

```
demo1 <- runif(1000)
demo2 <- runif(1000)
system.time({
  myarr <- array(1:n, dim = c(length(demo1), length(demo2)))

  for (p in 1:length(demo1)){
    for (q in 1:length(demo2)){
        myarr[p,q] <- demo1[p]*demo2[q]
    }
  }
})
#round about 6.8s on my system
system.time(demo1 %o% demo2)
#round about 0.01s on my system
```

Comment: As an additional information to *vectorization*: This is a informative article about it with a lot of other references within: http://www.noamross.net/blog/2014/4/16/vectorization-in-r--why.html